# What is the smalles sigma algebra that contains all one point sets?

Tags: measure-theory

I thought at first this was the borel sigma algebra, but if we have an interval (a,b) we need uncountably many points to construct it, which can't be done because in a sigma algebra we can only construct sets with countable unions. So secondly i thought it was just the powerset of the whole space, $P(X)$. this certainly contains all points, but is the largest sigma algebra one can imagine. Maybe there is a smaller sigma algebra so i am not sure about this.

Any suggestions?

Kees

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal M = \{E : E\ \text{ is countable} \} \cup \{E : X \setminus E \ \text{ is countable}\}$.

Comment: In particular, it is $\mathcal{P}(X)$ iff $X$ is countable itself.

Comment: i understand the first part of this sigma algebra, with one point sets one can take the union of al to make countable sets, but why do we include the term on the right side, what goes wrong if we don't..

Comment: A $\sigma$-algebra must be closed with respect to complementation. If $E \in \mathcal M$ you must have $X \setminus E \in \mathcal M$ too.

Comment: of course! thanks mate